# My compiled file doesn't have an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, file-extension

I'm using VSCode on a MacBook Air. I have installed GCC to compile C files. Basically, when I try to compile a file with the keyboard shortcut, it works perfectly: file.out is generated, but, when I try to compile it using the "Run Code" button, on top-right, the file still gets compiled, but I get generated a file with no extension (which still works, but I don't think I can include it in a .gitignore file)

I tried creating a tasks.json file (in .vscode), in which I specified that I want my file to have a ".out" extension, but, apparently, clicking the "Run Code" button just ignores it.

I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file with no extension to gitignore, it will get picked up.

If you compile the file with `gcc file.c`, the default output file is `a.out`, which is a relic of Unix (MacOS is a derivative of it).

You can use `gcc file.c -o outputFile` to set the name of the output file. In this case, the generated output file doesn't have an extension. If you add this command to `args` field in your `tasks.json` file, you can use `Run and Debug` tab on the left side to run the program this way.

I am not sure about Code Runner, as I haven't used it.

Alternatively, you can compile and link your project with CMake.